# Trying to use 3D on a 2D project: planes override each other

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got a problem when trying to use 3D on a 2D project.
I've setup 3 planes and I'm trying to rotate the center.
When I do this, the planes that are supposed to go "behind" stay on top of the other ones!

I don't know how to explain than the small video here:

https://youtu.be/RBeHNxRLjko

PS: it's the first time I'm doing this, if it's against SO rules I'm sorry.

Comment: You should probably be using worldspace canvases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by creating 4 canvas: one canvas for each side, and I move the camera around.