# Unity 2018.1: Buttons not responding in all canvas but the first one

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been searching in all forums for a while but no answers:

I've almost answered to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594033/trying-to-use-3d-on-a-2d-project-planes-override-each-other) by creating 4 canvas: one canvas for each side, and I move the camera around.
This seems to work... for the animation, but not for the UI: all the buttons except the ones one on the first canvas, dont respond. I've done what's suggested all around:

- add a GraphicRaycaster component to all canvas objects
- make sure there's an EventSystem object

But no success. the buttons are not responding in all canvas but the first one. What could I do wrong?

Comment: Doesn't that mean that the firs UI is blocking the rest? Why are you sing 4 Canvas at the-same time? Why not just use one or only activate one when needed?

Comment: Can you provide som code of what is going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got it working, what is did was:

To set up the scene:

1. Created two worldspace canvases with a button each
2. Rotated one 90 degrees
3. Put a perspective camera looking at them both.

At this point, i can only use one of the buttons.

However if i de-tick the "Ignore Reversed Graphics"-checkbox on the "Graphics Raycaster"-component of the second canvas, i can click both buttons.

Reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-GraphicRaycaster.html